# How do I get parameters from the superclass?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, parameters, super

Ok so I have this class Insurance and its constructor.

```
public class Insurance
{
protected String pNum, pDate;
protected int yPrem;

public Insurance(String pNum, String pDate, int yPrem)
{
    this.pNum = pNum;
    this.pDate = pDate;
    this.yPrem = yPrem;
}
}
```

How do I make the Auto extends Insurance class?  Do I need to pass all the parameters of the super class to the subclass as such?

```
public class Auto extends Insurance
{
private String vehicleID, make, model;
private int year, accidents, age;

public Auto(String pNum, String pDate, int yPrem, String vehicleID,
        String make, String model, int year, int accidents)
{
    super(pNum, pDate, yPrem);
    this.vehicleID = vehicleID;
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
    this.accidents = accidents;
    age = 2014-year;
}
}
```

Does the parameter list for Auto really need to have all the parameters from the super class in it?
*For clarification, there is also a Property class that extends the Insurance class.*

Comment: Yes, you're doing it right.

Comment: Only two things look unfinished here: 1) the hard-coded 2014 (what happens when you run your program next year?), and 2) the data model of storing the age (which will inherently become incorrect each year and will need to be updated) rather than the vehicle's manufacture date (which will never change).  But as far as your approach, you're doing the right thing.

Comment: As noted in the comments on @rgettman's answer, your classnames could also be a bit more precise.  I believe you meant for them to be `InsurancePolicy` and `AutoInsurancePolicy` (and that `Auto` referred to the insurance policy for a car, not to the car itself), so if that's true you should probably rename them to make them clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the only `public` constructor for `Insurance` contains 3 parameters, the `Auto` constructor must call it, passing 3 arguments.

But those arguments don't technically have to come from `Auto` constructor itself.  While it makes sense to have them coming from the parameters of the `Auto` constructor as you have it, you *could* technically pass literals, but that wouldn't make much logical sense here, as that would restrict what could be passed to `Insurance`.

```
public Auto(String vehicleID,
    String make, String model, int year, int accidents)
{
    super("someNumber", "20140710", 500);
    this.vehicleID = vehicleID;
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
    this.accidents = accidents;
    age = 2014-year;
}
```

If `Auto` is to subclass `Insurance`, then the way you already have it is the best way, even though it's not technically required to be that way by Java.

But is an `Auto` an `Insurance`?  There is a design issue.  Perhaps a `Car` needs to *have* an `Insurance` instead.  (Or a `Person` *has* an `Auto` and *has* an `Insurance`).

Comment: I think `Auto` was intended to be `AutoInsurance`, and should probably be renamed as such.

Answer (score 0):

No. Add a default constructor in Insurance without any parameters.
public Insurance() {
}

Calling this constructor will initialize the object with the parameters in Insurance defaulting to null.

Comment: Sure, but if all of those attributes are required (as is probably the case for the OP's particular domain), then you're going to have to expose and call setters for them anyway and you lose the guarantee that they have actually gotten set.  So yes, what you say is possible, but it doesn't appear to make sense for the OP's example.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not necessary. It depends on the design of your class. You can also use constructor chaining to overload the constructors in the superclass.

```
public class Insurance
{

  protected String pNum, pDate;
  protected int yPrem;

  public Insurance()
  {
  this("10", "10-10-10", 10)
  }

  public Insurance(String pNum, String pDate, int yPrem)
  {
  this.pNum = pNum;
  this.pDate = pDate;
  this.yPrem = yPrem;
  }

}
```

In this case, your subclass should be defined as follows:

```
  public class Auto extends Insurance
  {
      private String vehicleID, make, model;
      private int year, accidents, age;

  public Auto(String vehicleID, String make, String model, int year, int accidents)
 {

 super(); //If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the
         //compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the
          // superclass
 this.vehicleID = vehicleID;
 this.make = make;
 this.model = model;
 this.year = year;
 this.accidents = accidents;
 age = 2014-year;
 }

}
```